# Is there a way to store a variable in a SELECT statement?

Tags: mysql

Within a `SELECT` statement, I perform a calculation on the current row and store it in a column which I give an alias. MySQL 5.5.4 doesn't allow for referencing a column alias as described [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/problems-with-alias.html).

Is there a way to achieve the ideal code as shown below? I would like to avoid making the same calculation over and over. I figure that storing the initial result of the calculation to a variable (unique to each row) and referencing that variable would make the most sense.

**Code that works:**

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), example_table.date_start) AS daysElapsed
FROM
  example_table
WHERE
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), example_table.date_start) > 30
  AND
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), example_table.date_start) < 60
;
```

**Ideal code:** (that doesn't work because you cannot reference a column alais)

```
SELECT
  DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), example_table.date_start) AS daysElapsed
FROM
  example_table
WHERE
  daysElapsed > 30
  AND
  daysElapsed < 60
;
```

I have simplified the problem in this example. My actual code has a larger calculation which gets called multiple times, probably making this optimization worthwhile.

Comment: HAVING without GROUP BY comports as WHERE but it sees aliases.

Comment: @Mihai I do not understand what you just wrote. Could you please expand on it?

Comment: Replace where with having.

Comment: @Mihai This worked quite nicely. You should have posted it as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL, in general, does not allow column aliases in the `where` clause.  It does, however, allow column aliases in the `having` clause.  So, you can do:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(example_table.date_start, CURDATE()) AS daysElapsed
FROM example_table
HAVING daysElapsed > 30 AND daysElapsed < 60;
```

In most dialects of SQL, this would either be an error (`having` with no `group by`) or a global aggregation (i.e., always returns one row).  In MySQL, the `having` behaves like a `where`, in this case.

Using standard SQL, you would use a subquery:

```
select daysElapsed
from (SELECT DATEDIFF(example_table.date_start, CURDATE()) AS daysElapsed
      FROM example_table
     ) et
where daysElapsed > 30 AND daysElapsed < 60;
```

You can also do this in MySQL.  But, MySQL tends to materialize subqueries, so the performance would probably worse than for the first version using `having`.

Comment: Fantastic, using `HAVING` instead of `WHERE` worked just fine! My problem (not the example problem) also had some clauses that needed to be in the `WHERE`, and they continued to work just fine after adding `HAVING` without a `GROUP BY`.